# phpMyAdmin with Docker not using SSL when connecting to AWS RDS instance

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

I am using phpMyAdmin docker image to connect to a AWS RDS instance and need it to use SSL.  Everything is set as directed by PMA [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?#amazon-rds-aurora-with-ssl) but it will not use SSL.

Both config.user.inc.php and rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem are being copied to /etc/phpmyadmin directory when container is created.

When logging into DB server, PMA shows Server connection: SSL is not being used.
When database user in RDS is set to SSL required login fails and when set to not require SSL I am able to login OK. Hopefully someone can help me out with this.

Docker Compose

```html
version: '3.1'

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: somerdsserver.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - /home/centos/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
      - /home/centos/phpmyadmin/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem:/etc/phpmyadmin/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

config.user.inc.php

```html
<?php

// Address of your instance
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'somerdsserver.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
// Use SSL for connection
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
// Enable SSL verification
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = true;
// You need to have the region CA file and the authority CA file (2019 edition CA for example) in the PEM bundle for it to work
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/etc/phpmyadmin/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem';
```

Comment: Perhaps you just didn't copy and paste that part, but your config.user.inc.php needs to start with `<?php` as the first line. If you already have that, try adding a line at the very end like `die("Configuration loaded");` and try loading phpMyAdmin again (you should see a white page with only that text), this will confirm that the configuration is loading correctly. Let us know the outcome of those two things then I'll try to have some more ideas.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch Yes, I didn't c/p the opening PHP tag,  It is in the file.  I added die("Configuration loaded"); and did see a white page with the text Configuration loaded.

Comment: Try adding `$i=1;` after <?php